# How to return an array with values at given indices replaced by new values?

Tags: python, numpy

I can set values in an array with given indices like so:

```
>>> a=np.arange(5)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[[1,3,4]]=[-1,-2,-3]
>>> a
array([ 0, -1,  2, -2, -3])
```

This also works with a boolean mask. The functions `np.put` and `np.putmask` both do the same thing, but do so by modifying the original array. Is there a way to do this without modifying the original array or copying it? An example of what I'm looking for:

```
>>> a=np.arange(5)
>>> np.foo(a, [1,3,4], [-1,-2,-3])
array([ 0, -1,  2, -2, -3])
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Make a copy with `.copy()` and do the edits there?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't want to copy it

Comment: Why don't you want to copy it?

Comment: @swhat You can't expect b and a to be different and refer to the same array.

Comment: Well, copying the array was the obvious solution but I don't want to use the additional resources and it seems ugly anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to use additional resources, then you would have to only work with the original array, which means you would have to modify it. If you don't want to modify the original array, then you would have to use additional resources.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what do you mean by that? the second block was meant to demonstrate that the function outputs the correct result while the original array is unchanged

Comment: @swhat In effect, what you want is to modify the array _WITHOUT MODIFYING IT_.

Comment: @swhat In that case I am very confused as to what you want to do. Do you want to modify an array without modifying your original? Because in that case there will have to be two. It doesn't make any sense to be able to refer to one array and expect it to exist as two distinct sets of array values.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I think you hit the nail on the head. I'll flag this question as something unlikely to be reproduced nor a help to future readers, since obviously there's no reason to want to modify an array *without* modifying it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, I especially appreciate how you make vague statements and become increasingly condescending about it. For future reference, the constructive answer would be along the lines of "The fastest way to do this is to make a copy of it or modify the original array" and if you want to be MORE helpful, then also "a function with that signature does not exist in numpy"

Comment: @swhat I didn't mean to be rude. I apologise. However, what you wanted to hear is exactly what people have been telling you. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @swhat And for the record, I did not down vote. I believe this would be possible to do if there was some way to override the `__setitem__` slot function of arrays, but I'm not experienced enough to know if it's possible or how to do it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Right, I was a little too passive aggressive in that reply too. Because I'm still curious, it seemed to me that there would be a significantly faster way to modify those elements than by copying the array then modifying the new array, and instead having that functionality described be implemented already by numpy, which is why I asked the question. Was I mistaken about the efficiency bit?

Comment: @swhat What you can do is to make a copy of _just_ the indices you want to modify and change those, rather than change the whole array. That should improve the efficiency rather than making a copy of the whole thing. Also, you're not mistaken about anything. It's just that what you want is kinda impossible with numpy (at least, from the pov of everyone here).

Comment: @DavyM I believe I didn't communicate my question as effectively as I could have, but I still don't think that it isn't a useful question, even if the answer was "Such a function doesn't exist, so your best solution is to do x" from coldspeed

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Actually, I don't think that would avoid copying the whole thing because to make the final array you'd still need to apply the changes to the original array somehow, which brings you back to the original problem.

Comment: @swhat Check my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the elements on a copy of the array.

```
a = np.arange(5)
a
>np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array(a)
b[[1, 3, 4]] = [-1, -2, -3]
a
>np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b
>np.array([0, -1, 2, -2, -3])
```

EDIT: Note that Python follows [Command-query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) very strictly, except in cases that are obviously not going to do any harm (such as with `list.pop`). Thus, it is neither encouraged nor possible to both change items in a list and return that list. However, seeing as you would most likely have to store the altered list in some way, there is negligible performance slowdown from first copying the original list and then changing the elements in that list.

If you really really wanted to, you can probably override the `__setitem__` method of `np.ndarray` or create a new subclass of `np.ndarray` and override `__setitem__` for that instead, but again, there isn't really any need to do that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't want to copy it either. I edited the original question.

Comment: @swhat I think you should know that what you want to do _requires_ a copy to be made.